# How can I test certain elements are being rendered in my component asynchronously?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-testing-library

I am working on updating my portfolio project which is built using React, and I've recently started learning about testing using Jest and React Testing Library, so I wanted to refactor the project to incorporate tests.

I have 2 components that I am working with: `Projects`, and `ProjectCard`.

`Projects` is the container component that fetches project information from a local JSON file in the public folder and then for each project, render a `ProjectCard` component.

Here is the code for the `Projects` component:

```
const Projects = () => {
    const sectionName = navLinks[0].toLowerCase();

    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getProjects = async () => {
            const response = await fetch('./assets/Projects.json');
            const json = await response.json();
            setProjects(json);
        };

        getProjects();

        // cleanup
        return () => {
            setProjects([]);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <section className={sectionName} id={sectionName} data-testid={sectionName}>
            <Heading text={sectionName} color='maire' />
            <ul className='projects__list'>
                {projects.map((project) => (
                    <ProjectCard key={project.projectTitle} project={project} />
                ))}
            </ul>
        </section>
    );
};
```

What I am trying to do is simply check that there are a non-0 number of `li` elements (ProjectCard components) being rendered inside the `ul` element above. I eventually realized that since my elements are being rendered asynchronously, `getAllByRole` would not work, and have been using `findAllByRole` as it returns a Promise.

Here is the test code I have written:

```
test('renders project cards without error', async () => {
    render(<Projects />);
    const listItems = await screen.findAllByRole('listitem');
    await waitFor(() => expect(listItems.length).not.toBe(0));
});
```

The error I am seeing is:

```
Unable to find role="listitem"

<body>
  <div>
    <section class="projects" data-testid="projects" id="projects">
      <h2 class="heading text-maire">
        projects
      </h2>
      <ul
        class="projects__list"
      />
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

  16 | test('renders project cards without error', async () => {
  17 |      render(<Projects />);
> 18 |      const listItems = await screen.findAllByRole('listitem');
     |                                     ^
  19 |      await waitFor(() => expect(listItems.length).not.toBe(0));
  20 | });
  21 |

  at waitForWrapper (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:173:27)
  at findAllByRole (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:101:33)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Projects/Projects.test.jsx:18:33)
```

In addition to this, how do I go about performing tests for the ProjectCard component, since all of the JSX is rendered asynchronously? If someone could help me figure this one out, it would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to put yout findAllByRole in your waitFor ? `await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getAllByRole('listitem').length).not.toBe(0));`

Comment: @RomanMkrtchian I just tried your suggestion, but unfortunately I get the same error message as above.

Comment: Are you mocking `ProjectCard` in your tests? The `li`s are not being rendered inside the `ul` during the tests as you can see from the error message: `<ul class="projects__list" />`.